# Visual Studio Code 'django-admin' command not recognized

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, django-commands

'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file... So I am getting this error in terminal. I am trying to build an app. First I opened a folder(page) in my computer D drive and then opened Visual Studio Code. From there I opened the folder(page) and from view I opened terminal. Then when I am trying to type django-admin myproject page. it is showing this error.

Comment: Have you restarted VS Code since you installed Django?

Comment: Is Django installed in your machine?

Comment: @FelixEklöf I installed Django from extention in visual studio and restarted after that.

Comment: @AstikGabani sorry but do you mean in my python ?

Comment: Yes. you can check that by `pip freeze` command in teminal. And django should be in list.

Comment: @AstikGabani the thing is I have installed anaconda and not using my python in sytem . so is that a issue ?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using conda environment, use `conda activate` to activate the environment, and then you can use the Django module.
This error is occurring due to the missing Django module.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using a virtual environment, do you have it activated?
2. Is you you python scripts folder in PATH?

   On windows: Search for **'Edit the system environment variables'**.

   Click on **'Environment Variables...'**

   In System Variables look for row with variable name **Path**. Click on it and then Edit.

   You'll see a number of directories. Do you see one ending with something like `..\Python\Python39\Scripts`?

   If you have that folder open it and make sure you have **django-admin.exe** inside.

Comment: The thing is I have installed python after installing anaconda and having issue to inkstall python packages. So can I use anaconda enviroment in visual studio code ?